# LIM Package in R: Faster read of input

Tags: r

For solving linear inverse models in R there's an excellent package called LIM (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/LIM/).
The model problem is formulated in text files in a way that is natural and comprehensible. Functions in LIM then converts this input into the required linear equality and inequality conditions, which can be solved either by least squares or by linear programming techniques.

I have a text `File` with approx. 6000 lines (simple list of equalities, inequalities, components, parameters), which describes the linear inverse model.
I make it available to R for processing by following 2 lines

```
liminput <- Read(File)
lim <- Setup(liminput)
```

Problem:
The 2 lines need around 5 minutes to run.
*The first line Read command accounts for almost 100% of these 5 minutes.*

Question:
Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: this is going to be quite hard to answer, for two reasons.  (1) It uses a particular add-on package that's probably not very widely used (and hence potential respondents will have to dig in and figure out the details of the package before answering). (2) You haven't given a [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000).  ... Can you give more details?  How is the running time divided between the two lines you have specified above (slow reading/fast setup or vice versa or both about equal)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's going to be a very easy answer to this; you will probably need to find some way to re-write the `Read()` function for better speed (but see one possibility below). Looking at the `Read()` function in detail (in case you didn't know, you can print the source code by typing `Read`), it is essentially reading in lines and parsing them in R code.  Most of these operations will probably be hard to vectorize, and moderately difficult to re-write in `Rcpp`/C++ ...

Noam Ross has written a [very accessible guide to speeding up R code](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2013/4/25/faster-talk.html) (one of the first recommendations is "get a better computer").  There is really only one "low-hanging fruit" suggestion that might work without digging into the code yourself, which is to use R's byte compiler:

```
library(compiler)
Read.comp <- cmpfun(Read)
Read.comp(File)  ## **maybe** faster than Read(File) ...
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried your proposal to use compiler's `cmpfun()`. Unfortunately does not change anything when I benchmark with `system.time()` the version with vs. without byte compilation. I will now have a look into the code of `Read()` to check any speed potential.